# select closest values from two different arrays

Tags: python, numpy

suppose i have a numpy array

```
A = [[1 2 3]
     [2 3 3]
     [1 2 3]]
```

and another array

```
B = [[3 2 3]
     [1 2 3]
     [4 6 3]]
```

and a array of true values:

```
C = [[1 4 3]
     [8 7 3]
     [4 10 3]]
```

Now I want to create an array D, the elements of which are dervied from either A or B, the condition being the closest value of each element from array C.

Is there any pythonic way to do this? Right now im using loops

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
>>> K = abs(A - C) < abs(B - C)  # create array of bool
[[True, False, False],
 [True,  True, False],
 [False, False, False]]
>>> D = where(K, A, B)     # get elements of A and B respectively
```

Comment: Ah, so easy. I was fiddling around with `numpy.where` and all that but couldn't find a solution...

Comment: I think using `numpy.where()` would be the right solution: `D = numpy.where(K, A, B)`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach yes you're right, make this an answer and I'll upvote it. I think it also should be accepted answer.

Comment: @SvenMarnach virtual high five! :) I mean +1 :)